# Pandas - Unexpected results when indexing a DataFrame containing missing entries

Tags: pandas, indexing

First, we create a large dataset with MultiIndex whose first record contains missing values `np.NaN`

```
In [200]: data = [] 
     ...: val = 0 
     ...: for ind_1 in range(3000): 
     ...:     if ind_1 == 0: 
     ...:         data.append({'ind_1': 0, 'ind_2': np.NaN, 'val': np.NaN}) 
     ...:     else: 
     ...:         for ind_2 in range(3000): 
     ...:             data.append({'ind_1': ind_1, 'ind_2': ind_2, 'val': val}) 
     ...:             val += 1 
     ...: df = pd.DataFrame(data).set_index(['ind_1', 'ind_2'])                                      

In [201]: df                                                                                         
Out[201]: 
                    val
ind_1 ind_2            
0     NaN           NaN
1     0.0           0.0
      1.0           1.0
      2.0           2.0
      3.0           3.0
...                 ...
2999  2995.0  8996995.0
      2996.0  8996996.0
      2997.0  8996997.0
      2998.0  8996998.0
      2999.0  8996999.0

[8997001 rows x 1 columns]
```

I want to select all rows where `ind_1` < 3 and `ind_2` < 3

First I create an MultiIndex `i1` where `ind_1` < 3

```
In [202]: i1 = df.loc[df.index.get_level_values('ind_1') < 3].index                                  

In [203]: i1                                                                                         
Out[203]: 
MultiIndex([(0,    nan),
            (1,    0.0),
            (1,    1.0),
            (1,    2.0),
            (1,    3.0),
            (1,    4.0),
            (1,    5.0),
            (1,    6.0),
            (1,    7.0),
            (1,    8.0),
            ...
            (2, 2990.0),
            (2, 2991.0),
            (2, 2992.0),
            (2, 2993.0),
            (2, 2994.0),
            (2, 2995.0),
            (2, 2996.0),
            (2, 2997.0),
            (2, 2998.0),
            (2, 2999.0)],
           names=['ind_1', 'ind_2'], length=6001)
```

Then I create an MultiIndex `i2` where `ind_2` < 3

```
In [204]: i2 = df.loc[~(df.index.get_level_values('ind_2') > 2)].index                               

In [205]: i2                                                                                         
Out[205]: 
MultiIndex([(   0, nan),
            (   1, 0.0),
            (   1, 1.0),
            (   1, 2.0),
            (   2, 0.0),
            (   2, 1.0),
            (   2, 2.0),
            (   3, 0.0),
            (   3, 1.0),
            (   3, 2.0),
            ...
            (2996, 2.0),
            (2997, 0.0),
            (2997, 1.0),
            (2997, 2.0),
            (2998, 0.0),
            (2998, 1.0),
            (2998, 2.0),
            (2999, 0.0),
            (2999, 1.0),
            (2999, 2.0)],
           names=['ind_1', 'ind_2'], length=8998)
```

Logically, the solution should be the intersection of these two sets

```
In [206]: df.loc[i1 & i2]                                                                            
Out[206]: 
                val
ind_1 ind_2        
1     0.0       0.0
      1.0       1.0
      2.0       2.0
2     0.0    3000.0
      1.0    3001.0
      2.0    3002.0
```

Why is the first record (0, nan) filtered out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use boolean arrays i1, i2 instead of indexes

```
In [27]: i1 = df.index.get_level_values('ind_1') < 3

In [28]: i2 = ~(df.index.get_level_values('ind_2') > 2)

In [29]: i1
Out[29]: array([ True,  True,  True, ..., False, False, False])

In [30]: i2
Out[30]: array([ True,  True,  True, ..., False, False, False])

In [31]: df.loc[i1 & i2]
Out[31]:
                 val
ind_1 ind_2
0     NaN        NaN
1     0.0        0.0
      1.0        1.0
      2.0        2.0
2     0.0     3000.0
      1.0     3001.0
      2.0     3002.0
```